# Assigning variable = self creating a copy. Need it to be a reference (pointer)

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, ref

I am working on creating a matrix class for an assignment I have and usually if I assign a variable as `x = self`, x is a reference to `self` and thus all operations are in place. I have a function that reduces the matrix, and as an optional parameter I've added `inplace=False` such that:

```
if inplace:
    self = A
else: 
    A = self.copy()
```

Now normally when I do this, if I were to do an operation such as `A += B`, `self` would be modified. However, when I run `A.reduce(inplace=True)`, `A` is not modified. I've included the full class below and am hoping that someone can tell my why the operations are not happening in place. Thanks in advance.

```
import numpy as np

class matrix:
    def __init__(self, A):
        self.value = np.array(A, dtype=np.float)
        self.indices = np.arange(self.value.shape[0])
        self.shape = self.value.shape

    def swap_rows(self, r1, r2):
        ind = np.arange(self.value.shape[0])
        swap = (r1, r2)
        ind[swap[0]] = swap[1]
        ind[swap[1]] = swap[0]
        temp_ind = self.indices[swap[0]]
        self.indices[swap[0]] = self.indices[swap[1]]
        self.indices[swap[1]] = temp_ind
        self.value = self.value[ind]

    def add_rows(self, operations):
        # operations = [(c, row1, row2)]
        # where operation will be:
        # c * row1 + row2 -> row2
        for c, row1, row2 in operations:
            self.value[row2] += c * self.value[row1]

    # ... #           

    def reduce(self, b_ = None, swap=True, normalize=True, return_steps=False, inplace=False, debug=False):
        if inplace:
            A = self
        else:
            A = self.copy()
        if b_:
            b = b_.copy()
            if len(b.shape) == 1:
                b.reshape((-1, 1), inplace=True)
        if return_steps:
            steps = []
        # Normalize
        if normalize:
            A_max = A.row_max()
            A /= A_max
            if debug:
                print("A after normalization:")
                print(A)
                print("")
            if return_steps:
                steps.append([('normalize', A_max)])
            if b_:
                b /= A_max
        m, n = A.shape
        for col in range(n-1):
            # Swap
            if swap:
                # Check for max value
                max_ind = np.argmax(np.abs(A[:, col]))
                # Check if max is zero
                if np.abs(A[max_ind, col]) < 1e-30:
                    print('Matrix is singular')
                    if b_:
                        return A, b
                    else:
                        return A
                # Swap if necessary
                if max_ind > col:
                    A.swap_rows(col, max_ind)
                    if return_steps:
                        steps.append([('swap', col, max_ind)])
                    if b_:
                        b.swap_rows(col, max_ind)
            # Get constants
            cs = -A[col+1:, col] / A[col, col]
            operations = [(c, col, i+col+1) for i, c in enumerate(cs)]
            if return_steps:
                steps.append(operations)
            A.add_rows(operations)
            if b_:
                b.add_rows(operations)
        if debug:
            print("A after row operations:")
            print(A)
            print("")
        return_vals = np.array([A, None, None])
        if b_:
            return_vals[1] = b
        if return_steps:
            return_vals[2] = steps
        if inplace:
            return_vals = return_vals[1:]
        if return_vals.any():
            return tuple(return_vals[return_vals != None])

    # ... #

    def row_max(self):
        return np.array([self[row, i] for row, i in enumerate(np.argmax(np.abs(self.value), axis=1))]).reshape(-1, 1)

    # ... #

    def copy(self):
        return matrix(np.copy(self.value))

    def T(self):
        return matrix(self.value.T)

    def inverse(self):
        return matrix(np.linalg.inv(self.value))

    def flip(self, axis=None, inplace=False):
        if inplace:
            self.value = np.flip(self.value, axis=axis)
        else:
            return matrix(np.flip(self.value, axis=axis))

    def reshape(self, shape, inplace=False):
        if inplace:
            self.value = self.value.reshape(*shape)
        else:
            return matrix(self.value.reshape(*shape))

    def __add__(self, x):
        if isinstance(x, matrix):
            return matrix(self.value + x.value)
        else:
            return matrix(self.value + x)

    def __sub__(self, x):
        if isinstance(x, matrix):
            return matrix(self.value - x.value)
        else:
            return matrix(self.value - x)

    def __mul__(self, x):
        if isinstance(x, matrix):
            return matrix(self.value * x.value)
        else:
            return matrix(self.value * x)

    def __truediv__(self, x):
        if isinstance(x, matrix):
            return matrix(self.value / x.value)
        else:
            return matrix(self.value / x)

    # ... #

    def __matmul__(self, A):
        if isinstance(A, matrix):
            return matrix(self.value @ A.value)
        else:
            return matrix(self.value @ A)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.value[item]

    def __setitem__(self, i, v):
        self.value[i] = v


A = matrix([ [ 5,  6,  7,  5, -1],
             [ 8, -4, -1,  0, -3],
             [ 2,  1, -1,  3,  6],
             [-9, 10,  1, -4,  6],
             [ 9,  5, -5, -8,  4] ])

print("Original A:")
print(A)
print("")   
A.reduce(inplace=True, debug=True)
print("A after inplace reduce function:")
print(A)
print("")
```

## EDIT

Here is what I am trying to recreate in a simplistic way:

```
class obj:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def copy(self):
        return obj(self.value)

    def op(self, y, inplace=False):
        if inplace:
            x = self
        else:
            x = self.copy()
        x.value += y
        x.value /= y
        if not inplace:
            return x

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value)

x = obj(5)
x.op(3)
print("Copy:", x)
x.op(3, inplace=True)
print("Inplace:", x)
```

Comment: Please reduce that to a *minimal* example, not hundreds of lines of mostly irrelevant code.

Comment: `x = y` **never makes a copy**.

Comment: Are you actually calling `A.reduce(inplace=True)` at any point? ctrl-f isn't turning up any results.

Comment: I'm calling A.reduce(in place=True) in a script. The provided code is only the class definition. As far as irrelevant code, many of the methods defined are used in the reduce function, but I will try to trim it down as much as possible. And I understand x = y never makes a copy, but I'm confused as to why it seems to be in this example. I will provide a small script that to demonstrate

Comment: Okay, I've added some print statements to demonstrate what I mean. Running the above code will print A before the function, print twice during the function (after normalization and after row operations), and then finally after the function executes. I would expect the last two print statements to be equivalent but the last one matches the original, as if the function was executed on a copy of A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that operators like `+=` modify objects in place, but that's not always true. It only happens if the type of the object on the left side of the operator has an `__iadd__` method. If it only has an `__add__` method, then the Python interpreter translates `X += Y` to `X = X + Y` which is generally not an in-place operation.

So the reason your code doesn't do what you expect is because you don't have an `__itruediv__` operator, and when you call `A /= A_max` (if `normalize` is `True`), you make a copy, despite your intention to be operating in place.

Comment: Thank you. I am still getting used to the operator classes and all the variations. This was very helpful